# Java Scanner.next(), printing from while loop

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I started scripting a little piece that could parse old-style .vmg files*. I thought to start with scanner utility so I could at first chomp out the messages one by one. This is what I got.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Strip {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            File file = new File("all.vmg");
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);
//          sc.useDelimiter("BEGIN:VMSG");
            while (sc.hasNext())
            {
            String string = sc.next();
            System.out.println(string);
            }

        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }


}
```

It compiles and runs fine. Although it will not print out a single thing. First I used the Delimiter that is now commented. Then thought there might be problem with that. So now it just uses it's default whitespace delimiter. But no lines to be printed anyhow. All I have to guess is for some reason the hasNext doesn't evaluate true?.
* .vmg files are text files in general format of

```
BEGIN:VMSG
VERSION:1.1
X-IRMC-STATUS:
X-IRMC-BOX:INBOX
X-NOK-DT:20110224T215100Z
X-MESSAGE-TYPE:DELIVER
BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:3.0
N:
TEL:+37999999999
END:VCARD
BEGIN:VENV
BEGIN:VBODY
Date:24.02.2008 21:51:00
Sample mobile text message 
END:VBODY
END:VENV
END:VMSG
```

I also tried to feed the script several other simple text files with nothing printed out.

Comment: Have you tried with `hasNextLine` / `nextLine`? Also it would be easier to use `List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("all.vmg"), Charset.forName("UTF-8"));`.

Comment: are you trying to read it line by line, or character by character?

Comment: I also tryed with hasNextline and print Nextline, results are the same. I would ultimately like to read them in as strings running from BEGIN:VSMG to BEGIN:VMSG (not from newline to newline).

Answer (score 0):

`hasNext()` matches *anything*. It uses pattern `(?s).*` when trying to look for matches.

Try using `hasNextLine` which uses newline as a delimiter.

Comment: That's not the issue.

Comment: Tried full Unix path of "/home/user/all.vmg", aaand also tried hasNextLine. Result is the same, compiles and runs without error - just not printing out anything.

Comment: `Initializing jdb ...> run
run Strip
Set uncaught java.lang.Throwable
Set deferred uncaught java.lang.Throwable
> 
VM Started: 
The application exited`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, based on your comment in another answer, the program is throwing something that you aren't catching. Change your exception type in your catch to the plain `Exception` class, that'll ensure you can catch any `Throwable`.

Once that's fixed, then you can tackle the actual problem.

EDIT: So I went and pasted the code you supplied into Eclipse, and the contents of the file as well, and ran it without a single problem. At this point, I have no idea what the issue would be, other than for some reason it can't find the file. If that were the case, however, it would've thrown a very visible error.

In any case, it appears you've solved it on your own, though again I'm at a loss as to why that works and your original doesn't.

Comment: OK, Newb here as you can understand don't know much bout exception handling in any case. BUt  catch (Exception e) didn't appear to catch anything either. So it seems it DOES?! complete the try block.

Comment: That's really strange, because from your comment to Nishant, there's an uncaught Throwable... hmm

Comment: Another way to debug is to drop System.out lines at every step so you know how far it gets.

Answer (score 0):

OK this got the script working. But I have no good idea how. So maybe someone can enlighten me on what happened behind the scenes so to speak. I post it as an answer as it is somewhat a solution and also because editing the original question would make it reallly long.

The differences are that I initiated the scanner object before while loop. And that I used filereader and bufferedreader for scanners input (although its manual says it should be fine with file object as per my first script)

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Strip {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
Scanner sc = null;
        try
        {
            sc = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader("all.vmg")));
            sc.useDelimiter("BEGIN:VMSG");
            while (sc.hasNextLine())
            {
            System.out.println(sc.nextLine());
            }
            sc.close(); 
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
           System.out.println("Caught Something whatever?");
        }

    }


}
```